# Construct a 3-Regular Graph that has a specified maximum matching

Tags: graph-theory

I've been attempting the following exercise for awhile now:

Construct a connected 3-regular graph G such that the size of the maximum matching
in G is at most $\frac{|V(G)|}{2} -2 $.

I'm not really sure how to approach the problem. So far I've just been trying to construct graphs with varying numbers of vertices $(n = 8, 10, 12, ...)$. I was wondering if there was a particular way I should be looking at this rather than brute forcing it.

Comment: There is one here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem.

Comment: @Leen Droogendijk: The Petersen graph has 10 vertices and a maximum matching of size 5. Then, $\frac{10}{2}-2 = 3 < 5$. Are you sure that your example is valid?

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps the task is impossible?

Comment: @Moritz: I was referring to the second picture on that page, not to the Petersen graph itself, which indeed has a perfect matching.

Comment: @bof: Yes, I realized that later. That's why I actually added an answer with a more general construction.

Answer (score 2):

This construction shows that there are cubic graphs with an arbitrary large number
of unmatched vertices for any maximum matching.

First we make an ornament: a cycle $C_4$, with a central vertex that is made
adjacent to 3 of the 4 vertices of the $C_4$.
This 5-vertex ornament is "almost cubic": it has one vertex of degree 2.
(This ornament is used three times in the second picture on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem)

Now we recursively build a family of trees.
Let $G_1$ be the claw ($K_{1,3}$) and let $l_1=3$ be the number of leaves of $G_1$.

Having built $G_i$ and computed $l_i$, we create $G_{i+1}$ by
making each leaf of $G_i$ parent of two new leaves.
This means that the number $l_{i+1}$ of leaves of $G_{i+1}$ equals $2l_i$.

From each $G_i$ we can make a cubic graph by attaching an ornament to each leaf.
Call the resulting graph $H_i$.

It is easy to see that $H_i$ is cubic and that every matching of $H_i$
has at least $l_{i-1}$ unmatched vertices.